# How do I make the IIS 7.5 Management Service start automatically after a reboot?

Tags: web-hosting, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

We're using IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 and making use of the IIS Management Service to allow web publishing from Visual Studio 2010. However, after a reboot, the IIS Management Service doesn't start automatically. IIS itself starts up fine, just not the Management Service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it running the following command line from an elevated command prompt:

```
sc.exe config wmsvc start= auto
```

Comment: The full name is the Web Management Service. There's also the Web Deployment Agent Service which I assume is related.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the service is set to Automatic startup in services.msc.